# Match only closing brackets

Tags: regex

In the following string I have to find only `1)` and `2)`:

```
"Dsfgdsf ghdsgtaq sadf 5hs a sdgewrg1) AF AFDS (1,1-3). sdfwurf sgwefasöpopwe qdasda (2,3-29). jkgwgvsd sdfawefas2)"
```

With `\d\)` I find all closing brackets.

With `\((.*?)\)` I find `(1,1-3)` and `(2,3-29)`.

How do I manage to combine both patterns?

Comment: This doesn’t look like a job for regexes, since bracket matching isn’t regular language.

Comment: Try `(?<=\p{L})\d+\)`

Comment: Please provide exact rules for matching those substrings. Right now, as you see, we are guessing.

Comment: you also want to select the character behind it ?

Comment: Thank you Wiktor. Your suggestion works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to match  1 or more digits with a `)` after them only if preceded with a letter.

You may use

```
(?<=\p{L})\d+\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yaysom/1).

**Details**

- `(?<=\p{L})` - a positvie lookbehind requiring  a letter to be present immediately to the left of the current position
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\)` - a literal `)`.

Comment: It turned out, that the specification on matching wasn't complete. The new string looks like: 'Dsfgdsf ghdsgtaq sadf 5hs a sdgewrg.1) AF AFDS (1,1-3). sdfwurf sgwefasöpopwe,4) qdasda (2,3-29). jkgwgvsd sdfawefas2)' and I have to match '1)', '4' and '2'. I tried additionally with '\p{P}' but no success. Any further suggestions?

Comment: @FishermansFriend: What is the language/regex flavor? PHP/PCRE?

Comment: @FishermansFriend The solutions may vary depending on the regex flavor. In PHP/PCRE, you may match and skip all digits/commas/hyphens inside parentheses first and then match digit(s) + `)` in all other contexts. See [`\(\d[\d,-]*\)(*SKIP)(*F)|\d+\)`](https://regex101.com/r/Yaysom/2).

Comment: @FishermansFriend: Ok, in Java, just remove the PCRE verbs and use a capturing group around `\d+\)` part to grab just Group 1 values when Group 1 matches a string portion. See [this Java demo](http://ideone.com/eqnJ7q).